# How do I move the ribbon and menu to same level in Outlook 365?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, windows-11, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

To save space I want to move the menu to the title bar where search box and other icons are there. How do I do that?

It is Windows 11 with Office 365.

[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office 365 products do not currently support doing this.

This "menu" is actually the controls for switching the active Ribbon, they are not "menus" in the historic sense of the word.

While you can adjust the Quick Access commands quite a bit, including switching their location between the header and below the ribbon, and you can adjust the ribbons that are active and the controls that are active in them, there is not a setting that allows placing the Ribbon controls into the title bar/application header, or on the same row as the Quick Access controls.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Office is pretty customizable. I would try to see if you can manually add these menues to the quick access bar, and then hide the menubar itself.

Comment: The "menu" consists of the Ribbon headers and the File button, which opens whatever that "Back page" view is called now. These controls are part of the ribbon itself, so OP is asking to compact the Ribbon bar into the title bar. While There are a lot of commands you can add to the Quick Access toolbar (the commands to the right of the Search field), "File" is not one of those, and I did not see any commands that correspond to ribbon switching controls.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this: Customize the ribbon in Office
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31

What you can customize: You can personalize your ribbon to arrange tabs and commands in the order you want them, hide or unhide your ribbon, and hide those commands you use less often. Also, you can export or import a customized ribbon.

What you can't customize: You can't reduce the size of your ribbon, or the size of the text or the icons on the ribbon. The only way to do this is to change your display resolution, which would change the size of everything on your page.